# refresh div in a html page (web2py)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web2py

Hi I am starting using web2py. I have a page web Test.html in view with a div: .
On the other hand, I have a page web in the same folder: Test2.html with some code in python:

```
{{items = ['a', 'b', 'c']}}
{{i=1}}
<table>
{{for item in items:}} 
    <tr>
        <td></br>SOME CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
{{i=i+1}}
{{pass}}
</table>
```

How can I do to put the Test2.html content in the div IDtest? any example? Thanks. The goal is to learn how to insert a dynamic table in IDtest. I mean, I would refresh the IDtest content afther pushing a button for example....

LAST TEST:
I have tested

```
<script src="{{=URL('static', 'js/jquery.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script> ... and then <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() { setInterval(function() {var url ='{{=URL('Test2.html')}}'; jQuery('#IDtest').load(url);alert("HELLO");}, 5000); }); I can see the HELLO evrey 5 seconds but nothing in div... any sugestions?
```

I can see HELLO every 5 seconds but nothing happens related to div... It seems the load doesn't work... Any solutions? I have read on the net that load works on the server side but I don't know how to translate that in web2py?

Answer (score 1):

Expecting you have the Jquery libary loaded:

```
$('#IDtest').load('Test2.html');
```

Comment: this is the javascript / jQuery code, you want to execute on button click. For example you can add an onClick handler to any element by putting this script below the clickable element in Test.html: `<script>$('#IdOfClickableElement').click(function(){$('#IDtest').load('Test2.html');});</script>`. As s.lenders said, you have to load the jQuery library before.

Comment: (Test2.html); needs to be inbetween quotes: ("Test2.html");

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I have tried it but the load doesn't work. I have added  <script src="{{=URL('static', 'js/jquery.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script> ... and then  
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {var url ='{{=URL('Test2.html')}}';
jQuery('#IDtest').load(url);alert("HELLO");}, 5000);
                }); I can see the HELLO evrey 5 seconds but nothing in div... any sugestions?